# Not able to post JSON array to my rest controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, post, model-view-controller, spring-restcontroller

I've a JSON Array that needs to be consumed at the rest controller. It always says JSON parser error

```
{
"message": "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]",
"errorUid": "c794a587-2f27-4402-b43b-5ec46a5bccfc"
}
```

Here is my request object

```
{ 
"results":[{
    "keyname":"bb-response",
    "bbResponse":{
        "count": 8,
       "transactionId": "hu7h78707ssf8",    
        "responseMessage": [{
             "type": "NTY",
             "status": "F"          
       },
       {
        "type": "HYG",
        "status": "F"           
    }]}
}]}
```

Here is my code of the controller

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/post-keys")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public String postKeys(@RequestBody List<RequestWrapper> requestWrapperList) {
    log.info("Starting to send messages ");
     return "success";
}
```

My RequestWrapper Class

```
 public class RequestWrapper implements Serializable {

      String keyname;
      BBResponse bbResponse;
}
```

My BBResponse class is

```
 public class BBResponse implements Serializable {
     private int count;
     private List<Response> responseMessage;
     private String transactionId;
}
```

Can any one let me know where am I doing wrong? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The issue was with the JSON request. The correct request looks like this

```
 [{
"keyname":"bb-response",
"bbResponse":{
    "count": 8,
   "transactionId": "hu7h78707ssf8",    
    "responseMessage": [{
         "type": "NTY",
         "status": "F"          
   },
   {
    "type": "HYG",
    "status": "F"           
}]}
}]
```